# How to check what query is being executed with db.insert statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert a row in sqlite database. Below is the query:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_MAIN_ID_PK, "NULL");
    values.put(KEY_NAME, "name-1" );
long mainTblIn_id = db.insert(TABLE_MAIN, null, values);
```

For some reason, I am getting -1 as a result which is the data didn't insert. My question is that **how can I see what query is being executed when I am running db.insert(..)**. If I got the raw query then I guess it becomes easy to fix errors.

Comment: You would have to rummage through the source code of `SQLiteDatabase`. There is no "show me the SQL equivalent to this `insert()`" call that you can make.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Android's database API thinks it is a good idea to throw error messages silently away (but only for `insert()`).

Use `insertOrThrow()` instead.

Comment: ok, i got the data i was looking for in Logcat error messages. But i am still having some trouble. I have created a separate thread. Would be great if you can help me.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49017289/5700215

Answer (score 0):

### Note not a direct answer, rather an answer to the underlying issue.

I'd suggest that your error is due to `values.put(KEY_MAIN_ID_PK, "NULL");`

You are basically, assuming the `KEY_MAIN_ID_PK` is defined with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` or `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`,  trying to insert the string **NULL** (not a null) into a column that **must specifically have an integer** (i.e. the column is an alias of rowid, as per :-

> In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the
>   ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed
>   integer. [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

I'd suggest using :-

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    // values.put(KEY_MAIN_ID_PK, "NULL"); <<<< COMMENTED OUT HERE BUT DELETE
    values.put(KEY_NAME, "name-1" );
```

I believe that the following would also work :-

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_MAIN_ID_PK, null); //<<<< use null rather than string NULL
    values.put(KEY_NAME, "name-1" );
```